# Joomla not working on rackspace.

Tags: php, session, joomla, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I have several problems working with joomla on rackspace. We have tried everything and now stuck. Problem is that no help from them on this regard
When i try to set session handler as database then login doesn't work
and if I set session handler as none then sessions behaves absolutely madly.
when multiple users login then user is unable to see his own session data, and infact its showing other user's data.

wait and another irritating thing is that when I make changes in it and uplaod files to rackspace then changes don't even show. and if i delete that file, only then it shows error message, otherwise changes never show.

This all problem is occurring on Rackspace and other host its working fine. I am totally fed up. 
Please if someone may help

thanks in anticipation

Comment: We have quite a few clients running Joomla sites on rackspace with no problem. Try this little experiment, create a website from scratch on Rackspace and see if you have the same issues. I think it might be some wrong settings/permissions on the files.

Comment: I have already tried this with a fresh install of joomla. This issue was just happening with joomla. All others cms etc were working quite right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login doesn't need to write files, so it's most likely not a file permission issue.

session handler = database is the default and of course login works with it.  But this - complemented with having an error only upon deleting the file - points us in another direction: cache.

The Joomla! cache has several layers, but for each, if a hit is found in cache, the component won't be invoked at all.  But the file will be included.  Hence if you only see the error when the file is not there, Joomla! might be loading the pages from cache.

To prove that the cache is the issue and thus restrict your quest, what happens when you clear the cache? Does the first hit work? If so you know who's responsible.

But Joomla cache is designed to account for user interaction, and login usually works with both or either global cache and page cache turned on.

Which cache handler are you using? Can you try using file? Disabling the page cache (plugins-cache) solves the issue?  Are you using external cache handlers or any other system that may be manipulating the post data?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried deleting and disabling cache and now its working. but its really a headache to use joomla on rackspace. :-/
for anyone who has same issue, you have to disable cache to make it work properly on joomla

Comment: I have no experience with rackspace, but file-based cache should work in most situations if the user running the webserver has write access to the cache folder. And performance will improve a lot with page cache (10x at least)